# Getting users profile image in PHP via curl doesn't work

Tags: php, image, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I need the users image as image object within PHP.
The obvious choice would be to do the following:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
```

This works on my test server, but not on the server this script is supposed to run eventually (allow_url_fopen is turned off there).

So I tried to get the image via curl:

```
function LoadJpeg($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
  $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $img = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);

  return $img;
}

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';
$img = LoadJpeg($url);
```

This, however, doesn't work **with facebook profile pictures**.
Loading, for example, Googles logo from google.com using curl works perfectly.

Can someone tell me why or tell me how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

in this way you find the image
without it you get a 302 response code without image because is in another position set in the field "url" of the response header.

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest solution: turn on `allow_url_fopen`
2. Facebook most likely matches your user agent.

Spoof it like ...

```
 // spoofing Chrome
 $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, wie z. B. Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.215 Safari/525.13.";

 $ch = curl_init();

 // set user agent
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
 // set the rest of your cURL options here
```

I do not have to mention this violates their TOS and might lead to legal problems, right? Also, make sure you follow their `robots.txt` !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but setting the user agent does not do the trick.
Regarding the TOS: I am writing an app that does something with the users profile image for the user who is using it. I don't really see the problem here - or am I missing something?

Comment: I also tried to simulate an ordinary browser call by setting other header fields in addition to the user agent, but no luck there.
What really puzzles me is that imagecreatefromjpeg doesn't run into any of these problems; it just retrieves the image.